# What is the benefit of Redis Pool?

Tags: redis

Redis is a single thread database (for main operations). What is the benefit of creating multiple connections (connection pool) when operations process one by one at the server side? We can simply create a single connection and share it between all threads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bottom line is, it really depends, and it mostly depends on the client you are using.

### The case for connection pooling

Yes, Redis is single threaded, yes you can pass the same connections around to other parts of your application and reuse it. However the big thing missing here is that it's the latency that really gets you in Redis. Say you have a command that (for simplicity sake) takes ~ 2.01 ms from start to finish in your app.

1ms is the latency going to Redis
0.01ms is the command executing in Redis
1ms is the latency coming back from Redis

The overwhelming majority of the time (2ms of 2.01ms) the main thread of Redis is not in use so that 2 ms is essentially wasted. and if the socket you are passing around is not re-entrant while a command is executing over it, then you're blocked until the command finishes from sending anything else to Redis.

This is why you would use a connection pool, to allow multiple segments of your app to send commands to Redis at the same time.

### Some clients generally don't need them

There's a really important caveat that you have to make here. A client can pipeline commands to Redis, send multiple commands to Redis using the same round trips, and some clients do a really excellent job of managing this.

For example the main general purpose .NET Redis Client [StackExchange.Redis](https://github.com/stackexchange/stackexchange.redis) multiplexes all the commands you send to it through one connection, pipelining as much as it can. In this case there's relatively little wasted Redis time compared to what your application can send. Node Redis does something similar, automatically pipelining everything it gets in the same tick. In the case of such clients it's generally not necessary to pool connections without a compelling reason (e.g. very large objects whose transfer over the network might block other commands from executing.)